# KNN - Predict a single case in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, prediction, knn

I'm using dataset from Kaggle - Cardiovascular Disease [Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/camiloqq/nn-to-predict-cardiovascular-diseases/#data).
The model has been trained and what I want to do is to label a single input(a row of 13 values)
inserted in dynamic way.

Shape of Dataset is 13 Features + 1 Target, 66k rows

```
#prepare dataset for train and test
dfCardio = load_csv("cleanCardio.csv")
y = dfCardio['cardio']
x = dfCardio.drop('cardio',axis = 1, inplace=False)
model = knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
x_train,x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
# evaluate predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

ML is trained, what I want to do is to predict the label of this single row :

```
['69','1','151','22','37','0','65','140','90','2','1','0','0','1']
```

to return 0 or 1 for Target.
So I wrote this code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
single =  np.array(['69','1','151','22','37','0','65','140','90','2','1','0','0','1'])
singledf = pd.DataFrame(single)
final=singledf.transpose()
prediction = model.predict(final)
print(prediction)
```

but it gives error : **query data dimension must match training data dimension**

how can I fix the labeling for single row ? why I'm not able to predict a single case ?

Comment: If any of the answers solve your problem, please select it as a correct answer.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each instance in your dataset has 13 features and 1 label.

```
x = dfCardio.drop('cardio',axis = 1, inplace=False)
```

This line in the code removes what I assume is the label column from the data, leaving only the (13) feature columns.

The feature vector on which you are trying to predict, is 14 elements long. You can only predict on feature vectors that are 13 elements long because that is what the model was trained on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I asked is why prediction gives error and how can I fix it.
Yes, X is always in data science, the whole dataset without label, and Y the label set.

Comment: Yes, and I told you exactly why there's an error. The feature vector `single` is too large. `single is a vec of 14 elements. Your model only accepts vectors of 13 elements. The answer to your problem is to remove an element (probably the last element) @Federico

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a real and quick solution you can use this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
single =  np.array([['69','1','151','22','37','0','65','140','90','2','1','0','0']])
prediction = model.predict(single)
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the others, this is not a problem with including the target.
I had this problem too. The only way I got around it was to input part of `x`.

So:

```
x2=x.iloc[0:3]
```

then give the first row a new value:

```
x2.iloc[0]=single 

ypred=model.predict(x2)
```

and just look at `ypred[0]`.

Or try a dataframe with 2 values